# Groovy Integer can not be cast to Object[]

Tags: groovy, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I am working with a groovy script in SoapUI and I need to make a XMLRPC call to a server. I am using `groovy.net.xmlrpc.XMLRPCServerProxy` for this and invokeMethod needs a parameter as an object. The example that I am trying to use need an integer as parameter and now I've been casting this integer like a madman, but always keep getting:

> Caught: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast
>   to [Ljava.lang.Object; java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
>   cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;     at
>   xmlrpctest.run(xmlrpctest.groovy:17)

```
import groovy.net.xmlrpc.XMLRPCServerProxy

def base_url = 'http://www.cookcomputing.com/xmlrpcsamples/RPC2.ashx'
def serverProxy = new XMLRPCServerProxy(base_url)
def num = 1;
def response = serverProxy.invokeMethod('examples.getStateName', (Object)num)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
def response = serverProxy.invokeMethod('examples.getStateName', [num])
```

Have a look at the [API](http://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/modules/xmlrpc/src/main/java/groovy/net/xmlrpc/XMLRPCServerProxy.java). It expects the `args` to be a `List` or an `Object[]`.

Remember when you use `def num = 1` the type is always the wrapper object (`java.lang.Integer`) of the primitive.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast an scalar to array, the prefix [L means that the object is an array of java.lang.Object